DB2 Trigger on Table - Insert new record in same table on create
Good morning all,
Trying to create a trigger for db2 so essentially copy a field (trace number) change the type (trace type) on it for a specific client.
I've got the SQL for it (though I'm sure there are smarter ways to write it).
insert into TRACE (DETAIL_NUMBER, TRACE_TYPE, TRACE_NUMBER, EDI_IMPORT) 
select t.detail_number, 'Q', t.Trace_number, '0' 
from trace t 
left outer join tlorder tl on t.detail_number = tl.detail_line_id 
where  t.detail_number = '68030' and t.Trace_type = '6' and tl.customer = 'CROMAS' 

First time trying to create a trigger - thought this would be something simple - turns out I am completely lost.
I started going down this path - but unsure if this is even close. Also - wasn't sure how to connect the validation of my customer code (CROMAS)
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRACE_BT_CROMAS
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON TRACE
REFERENCING OLD ROW AS OLD
            NEW ROW AS NEW
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO TRACE (DETAIL_NUMBER, TRACE_TYPE, TRACE_NUMBER) VALUES (NEW.DETAIL_NUMBER, 'Q', NEW.TRACE_NUMBER);
END

